# How to include CSS Class in ActionLink in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My code is

```
@Html.ActionLink("test1", "Index", new { Area = "area1", Controller = "controller1" })
```

I want to include the following css class in the action link.

```
 class="rtsLink"
```

Also, can we add multiple css class. If so, I need to add another css class.

```
class="rtsTxt"
```

Update:

```
<li class="rtsLI" id="Summary"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:rtsXXX.OnClientTabSelected(this‌​, 0);" class="rtsLink"><span class="rtsTxt">Test</span></a></li>
```

Above I am replacing with following actionlink:

```
<li class="rtsLI" >@Html.ActionLink("test1", "Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "controller1" }, new { @class = "rtsLink rtsTxt"})</li> "
```

At first css is working fine. But when using Actionlink, css not working. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply add a new anonymous object as the fourth parameter

```
@Html.ActionLink("User Security", "Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity" }, new { @class = "rtsLink rtsTxt" })
```

Note that the word `class` is reserved in C#, so you must prefix it with an `@`.

Comment: Strange... there's no reason it shouldn't work. What does the rendered html look like?

Comment: have you included link to your .css file(on the page you are using this) where these classes are defined ?

Comment: It must work. Html.ActionLink usage is true. http://www.microtuts.com/asp-net-mvc-adding-a-class-to-a-razor-html-actionlink/

Comment: <li class="rtsLI" id="Summary"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:rtsMemoTextMenuContainerTabsManager.OnClientTabSelected(this, 0);" class="rtsLink"><span class="rtsTxt">User Security</span></a></li>
Above I am replacing with following actionlink:<li class="rtsLI" >@Html.ActionLink("User Security", "Index", new 
{ Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity" }, new { @class = "rtsLink rtsTxt"})</li> " At first css is working fine. But when using Actionlink, css not working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a `span` inside `anchor`. You could try this.

```
<li class="rtsLI" id="Summary">
   <a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { Area = "Tools", Controller = "UserSecurity" })" 
      class="rtsLink">
       <span class="rtsTxt">User Security</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thumbs Up.